# Webpack unexpected token error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I am using Rails 5 with react with webpack 2.1.0-beta.7.
With gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.7.0'.

However I got this error every time I try to run webpack.

```
Hash: 3aea6d8a27453c0be041
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.7
Time: 507ms
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./app/assets/frontend/main.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /mnt/data/Projects/kasih.in-dev/kasih.in/app/assets/frontend/main.jsx: Unexpected token (5:8)
  3 |   render() {
  4 |     return (
> 5 |         <h1>Hello world</h1>
    |         ^
  6 |     );
  7 |   }
  8 | }
    at Parser.pp.raise (/mnt/data/Projects/kasih.in-dev/kasih.in/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/mnt/data/Projects/kasih.in-dev/kasih.in/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:89:8)
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/assets/frontend/main.jsx",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/app/assets/javascripts",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: "babel-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

In case you need it, here is my jsx file:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    );
  }
}

let documentReady = () => {
  React.render{
    <Main />,
    document.getElementById('main');
  };
};

$(documentReady);
```

I am wondering what the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need install several packages, [`react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react) and [`es2015`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015),

```
npm i --save-dev babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015
```

and then add these presets to your webpack config

```
loaders: [{ 
  test: /\.jsx$/, 
  loader: "babel-loader", 
  query: { 
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']  
  } 
}]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Maybe I missed something when reading the docs but how could you managed to find what was wrong? Sorry, I am still trying to figure out how this works.

Comment: You are using `ES2015` and `React + JSX`, so you need appropriate presets packages, you can read more about babel presets here https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6